# Nginx with Nancy 504 Timeout error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nancy

I'm implementing the Hellow World project of .NET Core with Nancy. It worked fine and I'm being able to consume the service when running it locally as we can see below.

```
administrator@NewNancyServer:~$ curl http://localhost:5000
Hello from Nancy running on CoreCLR
```

However, when trying to reverse proxy using Nginx, even though I can see the "nginx welcome screen" at port 80 and the server is running, it always returns **504 Timeout Error**.

**NOTE:** I'm being able to see that the port is listening with **netstat** and all logs only show the "time-out".

```
2017/11/01 14:57:09 [error] 4411#4411: *18 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "localhost:100"
```

Below, I'll add my server configuration.

I'm using:

- Supervisor 3.2.0
- NGinx 1.10.3
- Ubuntu Server 16.04.3
- .Net core 2.0.2 and 1.0.4 are installed

#### Nginx configuration

**nginx.conf**

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Nancydemo**

File at "sites-enabled"

```html
server {
    listen       100;


    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

As asked by @Lundberg, here are my netstat output. Looks like it is listening in both IPv6 and IPv4

```html
root@NewNancyServer:/var/log/nginx# netstat -l -t -n | grep -E "(100|5000)"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:100             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5000                :::*                    LISTEN
```

---

## SOLUTION

After a lot of time looking into this problem, I came across a Microsoft documentation to address Nginx with Kestrel configuration. Diving into it, a new "site-enable" configuration was shown and, only adding a few configuration lines made it work perfectly!

The file now looks like

**Nancydemo**

File at "sites-enabled"

```html
server {
    listen       100;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

More interesting configuration and a full step-by-step can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Comment: Does `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000` also work?

Comment: Yes, it does work perfectly

administrator@NewNancyServer:/var/log/nginx$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
Hello from Nancy running on CoreCLR

Comment: Is the response slow by any chance?

Comment: Not at all, it is instantaneous. Looks like Nginx, in a certain way, can't reach localhost at port 5000

Comment: which host OS? Do you have SeLinux enabled?

Comment: Thanks @user3360862, a.k.a. Perrout. :) Could you paste the `netstat` output also?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lundberg! I posted the netstat output.

@Lalwani, I'm not using security on my Ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling: this could be related to IPv4 vs IPv6. Here is an example output on a server of mine:

`per@some-server:~$ netstat -l -t -n
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:113             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.8.0.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 88.80.6.225:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN`

The `tcp` lines are listening on standard IPv4 TCP ports, the `tcp6` ones are listening on IPv6. If a service is *only* listening on IPv6 and a client tries to connect using IPv4, it would break (and vice versa.)

Could you do a `netstat -l -t -n | grep -E "(100|5000)"` and share the results with us? I have seen strange behavior with `localhost` sometimes, where certain services were only accessibly using IPv6 or similar. It *might* be that the Nancy process only listens on IPv4, but the host is IPv6 enabled and `nginx` tries to access the upstream via IPv6 or something like that...